# RGB pictures detected as YCbCr with libjpeg-turbo

Tags: c, libjpeg

I'm using libjpeg-turbo to open jpeg pictures in a C program. Pictures in RGB colorspace are detected as YCbCr. Grayscale and CMYK colorspaces are correctly detected.

I though about a problem related to 2 different versions of jpeglib.h (where `J_COLOR_SPACE` enum is defined) or libjpeg conflicting with libjpeg-turbo, but there is just one `jpeglib.h` on the environment I'm using for compiling libjpeg-turbo and my program.

Any idea much appreciated.

Comment: Can you confirm libjpeg *ought* to be able to recognize "RGB" as a separate type? According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr), "Y′CbCr is not an absolute color space; rather, it is a way of encoding RGB information".

Comment: RGB too is not an absolute colorspace, sRGB is. Both RGB and YCbCr/YUV are on 3 channels, but ranges of the 2 latest channels may be different. I don't know how libjpeg determines input colorspaces. libjpeg.txt mentions: "By default, the IJG compression library will write a JFIF APP0 marker if the selected JPEG colorspace is grayscale or YCbCr, or an Adobe APP14 marker if the selected colorspace is RGB, CMYK, or YCCK.  You can disable this, but we don't recommend it.  The decompression library will recognize JFIF and Adobe markers and will set the JPEG colorspace properly when one is found."

Comment: jpeg written by libjpeg-turbo with a cinfo.in_color_space forced to JCS_RGB are also detected as YCbCr when reopened...